# What is the associative operator ⊕ in graph matching? and How does it works?

Tags: parallel-computing, matching

I read a paper about [Parallel Matching](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40047-6_66), and I didn't understand what the associative operator ⊕ in the following lemma/proof and how does it works in vertices and edges in the graph?

Lemma 3. Using our graph representation, each node v in the graph can apply an associative operator ⊕ to all edges incident on v in O(log|A|) time and O(|A|) work on the CREW PRAM model.
Proof. First, we read for each entry (v,$e_{k}$) ∈ A the value from E[k] on which to apply the operator. Next, we run segmented prefix sums with ⊕ operator on these values, where segments are the portions of A representing the neighbors of a single node. Finally, each entry of (v,$e_{k}$) ∈ A applies its result of segmented prefix sums to the edge E[k], while using the technique of Lemma 2 to avoid write conflicts. Each step of the algorithm can be implemented in O(log|A|) time using O(|A|) work.

Any sources can help me understand these concepts?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if you have any [associative operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) at all, then you can use the lemma to apply it to all edges incident on $v$.

There are many possibilities for operators that are associative, including sum, min, max, and many more.  You can use the lemma with any of them.